# Javascript or Jquery add to generic object with a foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, foreach

I am trying to recreate this:

```
formData = {
  'Username': $('input[name=Username]').val(),
  'FirstName': $('input[name=FirstName]').val(),
  'LastName': $('input[name=LastName]').val(),
  'Email': $('input[name=Email').val(),
  'DisplayName': $('input[name=DisplayName').val()
}
```

using a `foreach` on the `form` input:

```
formData = {
  function() {
    $('#Edit-@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId input, #Edit-@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId select').each(
      function(index) {
        var input = $(this);
        n = input.attr('name');
        v = input.val();
        return { n: v }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work. It's just descriptive of what I'm trying to do. The `n` and `v` values are correct. I can get the correct output through an `alert`. It's just creating the `formData` I'm having trouble with.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to solve it:

```
var formData = {};
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#Edit-@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId input, #Edit-@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId select');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  formData[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
}
```

Or if you don't need to support IE:

```
var formData = {};
for (var input of document.querySelectorAll('#Edit-@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId input, #Edit-@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId select')) {
  formData[input.name] = input.value;
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Cleaner and more efficient than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than I thought:

```
formData = {};
$('#Edit-@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId input, #Edit-@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId select').each(
  function(index) {
    var input = $(this);
    formData[input.attr('name')] = input.val();
  }
);
```

Comment: Since you didn't ask about jquery nor tag your question with jquery this is not actually an answer to your question